# Spacemacs trigger holy mode in major mode

Tags: spacemacs, hooks, repl

I'm using Spacemacs for clojure development and have gotten used to the vim commands mostly. However, when I start up a Repl I would like to only use `holy mode` with insert mode. Does anyone know how/if this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By `holy mode`, do you mean the normal emacs mode?

If so, you can easily switch between the two with `C-z`.

EDIT. To automate this for a specific mode, try using `evil-set-initial-state`.

I'm not familiar with REPLs, but maybe this can help. I use the following to switch to emacs bindings when using `org-brain`. Replace `'org-brain-visualize` with the mode you use in the REPL.

```
(with-eval-after-load 'evil
 (evil-set-initial-state 'org-brain-visualize-mode 'emacs))
```

This should go in the `user-config` part of your `.spacemacs` file.

Comment: Yes, I believe in spacemacs the two modes are Evil vs Holy. And you're right, switching is fairly easy as it is, but I would like to start a Repl in Holy mode (emacs bindings) by default, but have all other buffers use Evil mode as default.

Comment: I think you could use `evil-set-initial-state`. I'll try and edit my answer.